# How to get file from cloud storage and process as local file without downloading?

Tags: node.js, firebase, ffmpeg, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am working on a project where I have to extract frames from a video by using ffmpeg (node.js). I first upload video to firebase storage from my client, and then I want to process it in the backend server. However, ffmpeg only accept file as if it is stored locally.

```
const ff =new ffmpeg('C:/Users/alexh/Desktop/alex/name.avi');
```

It will not work with url. I am wondering is any way I can get file from url as if it is stored locally or firebase can provide me a way to get the file? I don't want to use filebase trigger event because I want to send http request to backend server.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) package supports operating on readable streams instead of just files. The GCS Client library supports [creating a readable stream for a GCS object](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.4.x/File#createReadStream). By combining these you can has ffmpeg operate directly from GCS.

Answer (score 0):

If you were running this on Linux or OS X, you could use [GCS Fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to mount the bucket on your filesystem and then point FFmpeg directly to it.